# Applying PDF watermark via a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I am working through the book 'Automate the boring stuff with Python' and I am trying to run the code to watermark a .pdf on all pages but the watermark only appears on the first page.

So the problem must either be in the loop or in the writing.  Can anyone help me figure it out?  Thank you

Running Python 3.5.0 on a windows 7 machine.

Code below:

```
import PyPDF2
minutesFile = open('meetingminutes.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(minutesFile)
minutesFirstPage = pdfReader.getPage(0)
pdfWatermarkReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('watermark.pdf', 'rb'))
minutesFirstPage.mergePage(pdfWatermarkReader.getPage(0))
pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
pdfWriter.addPage(minutesFirstPage)

for pageNum in range(1, pdfReader.numPages):
       pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(pageNum)
       pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)
resultPdfFile = open('watermarkedCover.pdf', 'wb')
pdfWriter.write(resultPdfFile)
minutesFile.close()
resultPdfFile.close()
```

Comment: You should move the watermark merging inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks juzraai- I thought that it was in fact adding it during the loop.  I understand now from your comment and cdlane's that it was just constructing the pdf, and not adding the watermark.  That wasn't clear to me just from looking at the code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import PyPDF2

template = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('yourfilw.pdf', 'rb'))
watermark = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('watermarkfile.pdf', 'rb'))
output = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
for i in range(template.getNumPages()):
    page = template.getPage(i)
    page.mergePage(watermark.getPage(0))
    output.addPage(page)

with open('water_marked.pdf', 'wb') as file:
    output.write(file)
```

Comment: It is usually helpful to provide a small amount of explanation going over what your code aims to do and how it works, instead of posting just code. Future users would greatly benefit it you edited this post and added a little explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that "the watermark only appears on the first page" isn't a bug, it's exactly what this code was designed to do.  I see no attempt to modify the code to add the watermark to every page.  Be honest about the situation and what effort you've put in to change it, even if "None".

Here's my rework of the code to watermark every page:

```
import PyPDF2

watermarkFile = open('watermark.pdf', 'rb')
pdfWatermarkReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(watermarkFile)

minutesFile = open('meetingminutes.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(minutesFile)

pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

for pageNum in range(pdfReader.numPages):
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(pageNum)
    pageObj.mergePage(pdfWatermarkReader.getPage(0))
    pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)

resultPdfFile = open('watermarkedCover.pdf', 'wb')
pdfWriter.write(resultPdfFile)

watermarkFile.close()
minutesFile.close()
resultPdfFile.close()
```

Try it out and see if it does what you want.

Comment: Hi cdlane, thanks so much for the help-  and also for the super snarky implication that I didn't put in any work to figure this out!  Here's the truth I'm new to python and trying to learn.  I took this code directly from the book as I said.  To me it suggests that the watermark should be added by the code: "Now that we’ve called mergePage() on minutesFirstPage, minutesFirstPage represents the watermarked first page. We make a PdfFileWriter object ❺ and add the watermarked first page ❻. Then we loop through the rest of the pages in meetingminutes.pdf and add them to the PdfFileWriter object"

Comment: @PaulS, I will consider 'SuperSnarky' as my new user name.  Reading the original code, it clearly just watermarked the first page and copied the rest verbatim.  I also confirmed this by running it.  You should be straight forward with your questions as I see far too many closed for lack of clarity before they even get a chance to be answered.